# How can I simplify a table with repeated but necessary elements?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[image: Data Example]

I want get the last date of each service

I would like to achieve the following:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|        Vin        |  Concesionario_Crm  |  OTS |   Fecha    |     Service   | Concesionario |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| JAANLR55EE7102074 |   AUTOCONSA UIO     |   9  | 23/04/2019 | MANTENIMIENTO |  AUTOCONSA UIO|
+-------------------+---------------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| JAANLR55EE7102074 |   AUTOCONSA UIO     |   9  | 10/09/2018 |    MECANICA   |  AUTOCONSA UIO|
+-------------------+---------------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I tried this but it just get the record when the selected service have the last date

```
Mantenimiento = "INSERT INTO SERVICIO SELECT DISTINCT t2.Mes_CRM, t2.Razón_social, t2.vin, t2.concesionario_crm, t1.ots, t1.fecha, t2.tipo_servicio, t2.concesionario FROM (SELECT max(t.Mes_CRM) AS Mes_CRM, t.vin, sum(t.ots) AS ots, max(t.fecha_salida) AS fecha FROM CASO AS t GROUP BY t.vin)  AS t1 INNER JOIN CASO AS t2 ON (t1.Mes_CRM = t2.Mes_CRM) AND (t1.fecha = t2.fecha_salida) AND (t1.vin = t2.vin) WHERE (t2.tipo_servicio = 'MANTENIMIENTO')"
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using joins on an aggregated subquery, e.g.:

```
select t2.vin, t2.concesionario_crm, t1.ots, t1.fecha, t2.concesionario
from
(
    select t.vin, sum(t.ots) as ots, max(t.fecha_entrada) as fecha
    from case1 t
    group by t.vin
) t1 
inner join case1 t2 on t1.vin = t2.vin and t1.fecha = f2.fecha_entrada
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler if you stored the dates as *date*s rather than spread across two columns.  But you could do this with subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from CASE1 as t3
        where t3.vin = t.vin
       ) as cnt
from CASE1 as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from CASE1 as t2
                  where t2.vin = t.vin and
                        t2.fetcha_entrada > t.fetcha_entrada 
                 );
```

The `not exists` gets the most recent year/month by saying that there is no other year/month with a bigger value for that `vin`.